# Legendary badge missing

Tags: support, daily-reputation-badges

I'm now over a month eligible for the [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary) badge, I think. My `/reputation` file says

```
rep cap was exceeded on 158 days
```

But I haven't received it. Have I misunderstood something about the calculation? Also, the file says

```
** total rep 84490 :)
```

But on the site, it is displayed as "84876". Does this difference have something to do with missing Legendary?

Comment: I was wondering why you hadn't gotten yours yet... I got mine when it said "148 days," so that count is clearly incorrect (or the badge computation doesn't match the count computation).

Comment: The difference in rep is normal. The display rep is higher than the `/reputation` rep for many users. If you get upvotes on an answer but the OP deletes the question, you lose that rep. The change doesn't show up in your display rep until the next recalc, though.

Comment: Also, __158 days__!? I am in awe.

Comment: It seems that Jeff and friends must not like you...

Comment: @James lol :) Maybe it's that first number that counts? It says "rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 137 days". Is that one above 150 for you?

Comment: No; mine are at 135 (first) and 156 (second) right now.  I remember reading somewhere that the second number was the important one, but there was tremendous confusion over the meaning of those two numbers too.  Maybe the server got confused as well.

Comment: @litb, @James: only the second number count. And there is no confusion about their meaning. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge

Comment: Weren't you told? The `Legendary` club can have only 35 people at once. You'll have to wait until someone dies, sorry

Comment: @Pekka, you have to be _in_ the club to be told the rules. Quite a Catch-22, that.

Comment: @Popular that's obviously not very well throught through.

Comment: @Popular as is the clause that someone has to die for new members to get in. Damn

Comment: @JSl Just out of curiosity, why the **edit** of your question mentions your name - usually it doesn't when the author and editor are the same?

Comment: @ring0 - check the history. The last edit was by Gnome who's no longer a live account.

Comment: @JSl So the last Edit is Gnome, but since it is disabled (or alike), your name is shown instead, as you are the previous editor=author. Right. Well, it's a convention - but I think it is misleading to show your name instead - even though Gnome is buried somewhere. IMO, Gnome in gray without rep (like when a question is moved to another server where the user does not have an account) would be intuitively more accurate. Anyway, I won't drop a question on *meta*, I just come from there :-)